# How Windows 10 does to refresh the notification area icons?

Tags: c#, c++, windows, windows-10

I know there are low level methods to notify the Windows OS that it has to refresh its UI.

Refresh the desktop icons.

```cs
[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
private static extern int SHChangeNotify(int eventId, int flags, IntPtr item1, IntPtr item2);

SHChangeNotify(0x8000000, 0x1000, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Refresh the environment variables.

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessageTimeout(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam, int fuFlags, int uTimeout, IntPtr lpdwResult);

IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff);
int WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1a;
int SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002;
SendMessageTimeout(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, null, SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 100, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Refresh the taskbar.

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
static extern bool SendNotifyMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, string lParam);

IntPtr HWND_BROADCAST = new IntPtr(0xffff);
int WM_SETTINGCHANGE = 0x1a;
int SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG = 0x0002;
SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, IntPtr.Zero, "TraySettings");
```

Refresh the desktop wallpaper/background.

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
private static extern int SystemParametersInfo(uint action, uint uParam, string vParam, uint winIni);

uint SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14;
uint SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
uint SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, wallpaperFile, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
```

But I didn't find the correct one with the correct parameters to refresh the notification area.

What is behind this UI refresh ?

[image]

Comment: Normally you don't need to do any of that; Using Shell_NotifyIcon would properly refresh the icon. The setting you mention does not *refresh* the icons, only hides some of them or none.

Comment: Did you make it working? Could you share us the proper piece of code?

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/el-gr/windows/win32/shell/notification-area)

Comment: Are you sure this is what Windows does to "refresh" the notification area when we click this on/off button?

Comment: no, this is a Windows setting you cannot change programmatically.